# Number and position of labels in Access Labels Report on current record correct in Print Preview but not in Print or Export

Tags: ms-access, printing, report

I try to create a label report from sub-form on current record. Bellow are  basic Subs.

Code Behind form button

```
Private Sub btnBlueLabels_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
Dim strDocName As String
strDocName = "rptBlueLabels"
strWhere = "AllocationAlphaName = """ & Me.frmSubAllocations.Form!AllocationAlphaName & """ AND AdvanceAllocationID = """ & Me.frmSubAllocations.Form!AdvanceAllocationID & """"
If IsNull(Me.frmSubAllocations.Form!AllocationLongName) Then
    MsgBox "No allocation records for this entity. The report will now close."
    Exit Sub
Else
    DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName, acViewPreview, , strWhere, acDialog

End If End Sub
```

Code behind Report

```
 Sub BDetailOnFormat(rpt As Report)
'Print a specified number of blank detail sections.
If intSkipPosition <> 0 Then
        rpt.MoveLayout = True
        rpt.NextRecord = False
        rpt.PrintSection = False
        intSkipPosition = intSkipPosition - 1
    End If End Sub


Sub BDetailOnPrint(rpt As Report)
       If intCopiesCout < intCopies Then
        rpt.NextRecord = False
        intCopiesCout = intCopiesCout + 1

    End If
End Sub
```

In the Print Preview everything looks good.

[in the picture: print preview pop up window - three of used labels skipped and three same labels needs to be printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR9QC.jpg)

When I try to print the Print Preview, it prints only one label (not three) and it located on the top and left position of a page.

[Print output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHmHZ.jpg)

Please, I am asking for advice!
Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you print directly to printer without first opening in PrintPreview?

Comment: It skips three used labels which is correct but it doesn't prints current record. It takes records from record source table.

Comment: Only first of these records - three, rest of others by one.

Comment: Where are you calling those two report procedures? If you want to provide db for analysis, I recommend Box.com fileshare site and post link to file.

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/k3tuu6cad4as3r4owjfzuyybmyvobtng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that prompts input boxes to set the public variables into the form procedure before the OpenReport line instead of in the report Open procedure. Declare the 3 variables in the module headers as Global and will be available to the form procedures. (My preference would be textboxes to input the Skip and Copies values then form code sets starting values for the global variables. Use textbox validation properties.) Do the validation in form so don't even call the report if inputs are not valid. Actually, put this code into a Sub that can be called by both buttons. The code currently in the buttons could be consolidated into this Sub.

This works going direct to printer. But PrintPreview to printer does not because the report events do not run again. This is an either/or situation - either to screen or to printer, can't do both.

Whether to screen or printer, report recordset is properly filtered.

Other Notes:

Missing `Option Explicit` in several modules.

BlueLabels and WhiteLabels modules are virtually indentical. Why not 1 generic module? They are not showing in Navigation Pane. Had to create new module (consolidated) and delete the old ones.

WhiteLabels `Sub WDetailOnPrint` procedure is missing the `On Error` statement.

The `Exit Sub` line in the `If Then` structures is not necessary. 
In fact, prevents execution of the `Exit_Procedure:` code.
This code has `Set Warnings True`. Why? Warnings are never set false.

RedLabelSecond textbox shows 'invalid control source' error, had to reselect the field to clear that.

Comment: Dear June7, I cannot express how grateful I am! I addressed all problems in the code, you recommended.

Comment: I am able to print labels without opening the report. 
I  use DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName, acNormal, , strWhere
Thank you very much.

Comment: If answer offered resolved issue, would be nice to mark it accepted. Glad you have it working now.